# Using the generalised binomial theorem to expand an expression

Tags: series-expansion, combinatorics

I would like to use Mathematica to compute the following expansion: $(1+x)^\rho= 1 + \rho x +\dots$ for some $|\rho|<1$ as for example explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series). I tried the Series expansion functions `Series` and `Expand` but somehow all resources direct me to binomial series with integer exponents.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `SeriesCoefficient[(1+x)^ρ, {x, 0, n}]`?

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

The coefficients for the series expansion are

```
coef[n_] = SeriesCoefficient[(1 + x)^ρ, {x, 0, n}]
```

[image]

Verifying,

```
Sum[coef[n]*x^n, {n, 0, Infinity}]

(* (1 + x)^ρ *)
```

[`Binomial`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Binomial.html) is also defined for non-integer values

```
Binomial[ρ, n] // FunctionExpand

(* Gamma[1 + ρ]/(Gamma[1 + n] Gamma[1 - n + ρ]) *)
```

**EDIT:** For a partial sum

```
m = 10;

(Sum[coef[n]*x^n, {n, 0, m}] // 
   FunctionExpand) ===
 (Series[(1 + x)^ρ, {x, 0, m}] // Normal)

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 3):

*I tried the Series expansion functions Series and Expand but somehow all resources direct me to binomial series with integer exponents*

See the following which does not specify the value of the exponent.

Do the Taylor series

```
taylor = Normal@Series[(1 + x)^a, {x, 0, 10}];
```

Do the binomial expansion following the wiki link

```
binomialexpand = FunctionExpand@Sum[Binomial[a, k] x^k, {k, 0, 10}];
```

Compare

```
taylor - binomialexpand
```

> `0`

So, they are the same